# how can i clear or reset the preferences for Adobe Flash Builder?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, eclipse, builder

I am using Flash builder 4 to both build and manage (via cvs) projects. In recent days my designer has been having trouble committing to CVS, leaving a project blocked.
I have <strike>troubleshooted</strike> <strike>troubleshot</strike> tested CVS and it is working fine (others can commit and retrieve without a hitch).

in an effort to start from scratch - I have removed the flash builder application (dragging it to the trash, its a Mac) as well as using the uninstaller (which does not work as well as I would have thought), but on reinstall - all preferences are still there - CVS connection and all.

is there a file or set of files I can delete to reset all of the prefs for Flash Builder (built on eclipse if that helps)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your workspace directory and remove the **.metadata** directory.  This is where Eclipse stores all preferences and project-settings.

You can find the workspace directory by navigating through the preferences:
 Preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown->Workspaces

Note: this will remove all configuraton for FB, not just those settings pertaining to a specific project.